# LLVM 7.0 does not provide specific Platform Toolset on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, clang, llvm

I've just installed the LLVM 7.0.0 for Windows (64-bit) released few hours ago.

With the new version, all the platform toolsets provided by the previous release (6.0.1) for Visual Studio 2015 (named "**LLVM-vs2014**", "**LLVM-vs2014_xp**" and "**LLVM-vs2010**") are not available anymore.

I've seen a new extension named [**LLVM Compiler Toolchain**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LLVMExtensions.llvm-toolchain) in the Visual Studio Marketplace, but it is not available for Visual Studio 2015.

Do you know the reasons of this lack?

Comment: No one prepared them, I guess. MSVS 2015 is getting old and LLVM is moving forward.

Comment: Similar topic has just been discussed on the mailing list[1]. Basically, no one did this as stated by @arrowd.

[1] http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-September/126274.html

Comment: Actually, the folder the folder `C:\Program Files\LLVM\tools\msbuild`, that contained all the MSVS settings (and a script to install them) is missing in the version 7.0.0. So, also the MSVS 2017 is not supported in this way.

Comment: Is this an oversight or has LLVM actually announced that they're discontinuing support for MSVS 2015? I have a really hard time believing it's the latter as they were still supporting MSVS 2010 as recently as this March. It seems weird to go from supporting a version that's 8+ years old to dropping support for all previous versions all at once without some kind of discussion happening somewhere.

Comment: To be clear, we are not discontinuing support for MSVS 2015.  We just can't make the extension install into VS 2015 because support for installing outside the extensions directory (e.g. into VCTargets) was only introduced in VS 2017.  So if we want the extension on the marketplace, this is the only way.  The compiler itself will continue to be compatible with VS 2015 and VS 2013 with appropriate flags.

It's worth noting that the old VS 2015 extension didn't actually work very well anyway (for example it would trigger a full rebuild 100% of time in debug mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Visual Studio extension appears to be compatible with Visual Studio 2015, despite official support not being mentioned. [At least one LLVM reviewer](https://reviews.llvm.org/D42762?id=132243#inline-374042) was able to install the .vsix in VS2015 out of the box.

I personally use the VC++ Build Tools 2015, and was able to get away with simply extracting the contents of the .vsix's `$VCTargets` directory into `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v140\`.

Comment: I'm the author of the extension (as well as the person who you mentioned on the LLVM review).  It turns out that my comment on the review was inaccurate.  If you set the manifest file to say that VS 2015 is supported, then yes it will install and appear to be successful.  That was why I left the comment on the review saying it worked.  But I didn't actually test it.  Turns out it doesn't actually do anything at all!  That is why I ultimately removed VS 2015 support from the manifest, so now it will not even install.  

The workaround you proposed here though seems promising

Comment: and although I don't have a VS 2015 installation to try this out, it seems like it would probably work.  Sorry I couldn't make the extension install into VS 2015, but it's just not supported with VS 2015's manifest format :(