# Is the LLVM-vs2014 toolset removed from clang 7 and 8?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, clang

Using clang 6.0.1 I can create MSVC projects with LLVM-vs2014 toolchain to build them with clang.
Clang 7.x and 8.x seem not to include such a toolchain. Is the feature deprecated, unsupported, or is there just another way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I does seem that the VS specific toolchains are not included in the later releases of Clang. You can always check what build tools are available by right clicking your project in VisualStudio selecting `Properties` and then look under `Platform Toolset`:

[image]

Another option is to use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LLVMExtensions.llvm-toolchain) visual studio extension which should allow you to use an existing installation of clang you have on your machine.

<s>Finally, starting with Visual Studio 2017, there is an experimental version of Clang that you can use as a platform toolset called `Clang/C2`. You'll need to run the Visual Studio Installer to ensure that you have installed it, but otherwise it should show up in the platform toolset as `v141_clang_c2` as shown in the image above.</s>

**Edit**: As per the comment below, it seems that `Clang/C2` has been abandoned and is no longer a good, long term option.

I've spent a lot of time in the past trying to get newer versions of clang to play nice with Visual Studio and it hasn't been fun (or fruitful). Hopeful this type of support gets better in the future. As a side note, if you're not generating solution files with CMake and instead use Visual Studio "Open Project" feature for CMake based projects, you may be able to manually set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to force the use of Clang.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using Clang/C2. [It has been abandoned](https://twitter.com/stephantlavavej/status/871861920315211776) and never really worked completely (e.g. optimized CPU instructions made it fail miserably).

Comment: @rubenvb I was not aware of this, I will update the answer.

Comment: I knew Clang/C2, but it does not have OpenMP at all and I need to compile the project with clang as MSVC does not support OpenMP 3.0. I am looking for an as easy as possible solution that works with cmake and the ``LLVM-vs2014`` toolchain was a great solution for integrating cmake, clang and Visual Studio.

Comment: @allo Well if push come to shove, you can always stick to using the LLVM-vs2014 toolchain, unless it doesn't support OpenMP 3.0?

Comment: I am currently back to LLVM 5.0 and the old toolchain. It would just be nice to upgrade a recent LLVM version as well. I think about closing the question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52407398/893159, what do you think? The question is about VS2015, but the answer for this question seems to be, that the LLVM project does not provide toolchains anymore and the VS extension might be one solution and creating an own toolchain definition another one.

Comment: @allo Yes that would be nice, but may be wishful thinking. Yes it seems that the question has indeed already been discussed.